# Connect apple wireless keyboard Model A1644 with ubuntu 16.10

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, 16.10, apple, bluez

I have searched online about this question, however, not work for me.
my ubuntu is 16.10, bluez 5.41, and I use default bluetooth manager. I have installed blueman, not work, either.

I can find keyboard after I turn it on and trust it in bluetoothctl

Trying to pair bdaddr, show me error, Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed

Connect it, show me error, Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed.

Could anyone help me on this problem, Thank you. I have tried many methods I can find online, but not work at all.

Comment: https://www.organicdesign.co.nz/Apple_wireless_keyboard_on_Linux

Comment: @CelticWarrior thank you for the link. However, is it out of date? I have tried this before. "hcitool scan" can't find devices, "hcitool lescan" can. "hidd" is instead of "bluetoothctl".

Comment: finally, I solved it. My laptop is Dell XPS 13 model 9343. Bluetooth model is BCM20702A, however, in /lib/firmware/brcm, I have no relevant firmware. This is the link of solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1589623